# Parse.com - send Push notification with objectId from Installation as parameter

Tags: parse-platform, httprequest

I'm trying to use the ***Parse.com API***.
I want to send a push notification to a spesific device by
using the **objectId** in **_Installation**.

This is the parameter I'm sending in my POST:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "alert":"Message to send"
    },
    "where":
    {
        "user":
        {
            "__type":"Pointer",
            "className":"_Installation",
            "objectId":"GfdbNwJhr6"
        } 
    } 
}
```

The response returns:

```
{
    "result": true
}
```

However I do not get any notification on my device...

Also I've tried changing `"user":"_type"` to `"installation":"_type"`

Still doesn't work...

Comment: why aren't you using channels ?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, found the solution:

```
    {
      "data": 
             { 
                "alert": "321213", "sound": "", "badge": "Increment" 
             },
      "where": 
             { 
                "objectId": "GfdbNwJhr6" 
             }
    }
```